# Shiny server-side navigate to URL

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app, and sometimes the session can end (server timeout, data error, etc).  This currently leaves them on a greyed out screen of the app.

To be more user friendly, I would like to refresh the user's session, or redirect them to the landing page of the app when this happens, so they can continue with what they were doing.

I would also like the code to work locally on my machine when coding, and when hosted on the Linux server.  I am planning on using `session$clientData$url_pathname` to make this work.  I currently (have in `server.R`) something like:

```
session$onSessionEnded({ 
  # (1) Get the current url
  currURL<-session$clientData$url_pathname
  # (2) Go to the current URL
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------
  #  I would like to refresh the browser here, using currURL as the path
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------
  # (3) Clear all session data
  rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
})
```

What command could I use in step (2) above to do the equivalent of the following in `ui.R`?

```
tags$a(href = "www.my-variable-url.org", "Click here to refresh the current URL")
```

Thanks